# Why my code can only run on windows xp 32bit system?[code generation]

Tags: c, visual-c++, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to write a program of generate x86 machine code, but code can only running on 32bit winxp. It says "Unhandled exception at 0x776315ee in tiny.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation." on win7 64bit, why？

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main()
{
    char *code = (char *)malloc(1024);
    memset(code, 0, 1024);

    char opcode = 0xB8;
    memcpy(code, &opcode, sizeof(char));

    int oprand = 2;
    memcpy(code + sizeof(char), &oprand, sizeof(int));

    char opret = 0xC3;
    memcpy(code + sizeof(char) + sizeof(int), &opret, sizeof(char));

    typedef void (* func_t)(void);
    func_t func = (func_t)code;

    func();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory allocated on the heap is protected from being executable by [DEP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It might be disabled on your XP machine or it might be something else, but whatever the reason is: instead of `malloc()`, you have to call [`VirtualAlloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with (at least) [`PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as `flProtect` to dynamically allocate memory from which code can be executed.

Comment: But note that unlike `malloc`, `VirtualAlloc` rounds the size up to a page boundary (probably 4 KiB).